# dict-list and Templates

Tags: excel, list, python-2.7, templates, dictionary

I have the following script, which works:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from string import Template

book = open_workbook('C:/Desktop/input.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# read header values into the list    
keys = [sheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]

dict_list = []
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value 
     for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}
dict_list.append(d)
print dict_list

form=Template('''Please review the following information

Issue Number:       $Issue
priority:     $Priority
ID:           ID
Name:         $Name
Date:       $Date



''')

first = {u'Priority': 3.0, u'Date': 41894.0, u'Issue': 1233.0, u'Name': u'Ekieta'}

print form.substitute(first)
```

I want the section first to be automated so it should always grab that data that is given by dict_list so I don't have to print dict_list first then copy and past. How would I do this?

Comment: Sorry ...Yes this is with Python. Thanks

Comment: Hello,Can someone please help?